# Javascript/jQuery outerHeight()

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Does `$('#idOfLememt').outerHeight();` yield same result for all browsers? Any thing different for IE7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/ with the different browsers you want to test and see for yourself (on Mac OS X so can't check IE for you). It looks like the DOM in the demo has all possible styles that would affect this included.

**Most of the time** you can rely on jQuery to do it's thing and give you consistent results across browsers, that's one of it's main reasons for being after all.

Edit: Of course this won't be the case if the browser messes up with something else, for example if your container isn't fixed height and IE renders something inside your container with a different height for whatever reason then the result would be different. You are however pretty much guaranteed to always get the same result as the amount of pixels used on screen.

Answer (score 2):

Like SLaks said it should work fine.

There is one downfall you might run into though if you aren't explicitly setting margins and padding in your CSS.  outerHeight() will include padding and border always and if includeMargin is true than it will also include margins. With some padding/margin discrepancies across browsers... ahem... IE... you may get different calculations unless you've explicitly set the border, padding and margin on the element in question.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine.  (Unless you have other layout issues)