# C# Javascript iframe resize

Tags: javascript

How do you auto resise an iframe after you've added content to a div in the code behind. I'm called

```
function resizeIframe() {
  parent.document.getElementById('iframe2').style.height = document.getElementById('events_calendar').offsetHeight;
}
```

but i'm about 20 px short. BAsically i've got a calendar that renders whats on on a certain day. this can be n number of lines. after i've popuplated that div in C# code behind I'm call resizeIframe() and not getting anywhere. i've tired style.height, clientheight etc.

Thanks
Frames

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is "outerheight".

see: [Javascript/jQuery outerHeight()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166295/javascript-jquery-outerheight)